# Rotation clockwise and counter clockwise with probability $p$ and $q$.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, simulation, python

> Consider a periodic Markov process, of size n, with probability $p$ of rotating clockwise and with probability $q$ of rotating otherwise. Write a program in Python and simulate that Markov chain.

I am not understanding this Markov chain once I cannot identify the transition matrix. Since we have just two probabilities of going clockwise or counter-clockwise. Is this not a random walk instead?

**Question**:

How should I approach this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem statement seems to be missing some details, but I presume it means that you have $n$ states arranged in a circle, and if you are in some state, you have probability $p$ of moving clockwise to its neighbor, and probability $q$ of moving counterclockwise to the other neighbor.

Comment: @angryavian Sorry for not having replied immediately. But I guess you are right. Do you have any idea on how to start solving the problem. What would be the Markov matrix?

Comment: @PedroGomes How does a single Markov step looks like?

Comment: Did you ever get the transition matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p = q = 1/2.$ Suppose states $S = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ arranged in a circle with $0$ adjacent to $4.$ At each step you move one state clockwise or one
state counterclockwise (probability 1/2 each). Then you are correct that this
is a random walk on the circle. But as for many random walks, this one is also a Markov chain.

I can show you how to program this random walk in R (in which `%%` signifies
modular arithmetic):

```
m = 10^4;  x = numeric(m)
x[1] = 0  # initial state
for(i in 2:m) {
  x[i] = (x[i-1] + sample(c(-1,1), 1)) %% 5
}
table(x)/m
x
     0      1      2      3      4 
0.1991 0.2068 0.2054 0.1964 0.1923 

plot(x[1:100], type="b", ylab="State", xlab="Step", main="History Plot")
```

If you write the transition matrix for this random walk, you will see that
it is doubly stochastic, so that its stationary distribution is 
$\sigma = (1/5,\, 1/5,\, 1/5,\, 1/5,\, 1/5),$ as approximated by simulating the
chain through 10,000 steps.

The chain is ergodic, so this discrete uniform distribution is also the
limiting distribution. [If I had used integers mod 4 (instead of mod 5), then the chain would
be *periodic* of period 2, hence not ergodic: it would be in an even numbered state at alternate steps.]

[image]

An ACF ('autocorrelation function') plot for the first 40 lags, shows that
knowing the current state is of little help predicting the state a dozen steps
later. (Google it if interested.)

```
acf(x)
```

[image]

*Note:* This $X$ chain can be used as an example to illustrate that a function of
a Markov process is not necessarily Markovian. Suppose we can only observe whether the chain is or is not in state 0. Then the observable process has $Y_i = 0,$ if $X_i = 0$ and $Y_i = 1,$ otherwise. For the $Y$-process, knowing the current state is not full information. If $Y$ has just gone out of $0$ then
it has a 50:50 chance of returning to $0$ at the next step. But if $Y$ left
$0$ a two steps ago, then $X$ must now be in state $2$ or $3,$ so that $Y$ cannot return to $0$ on the next step. The $Y$-process can have more than
Markovian one-step dependence. In particular,
$$\frac 1 2 = P(Y_4=0|Y_3=1, Y_2 = 0) \ne P(Y_4=0|Y_3=1, Y_2=1, Y_1=0) = 0$$
violates the Markov property.

Comment: $\sigma = (1/5,1/5,1/5,1/5,1/5)$?

Comment: Yes, discrete uniform on the _five_ states. See 'table' output in R code. Or write the transition matrix $\mathbf{P}$ and solve $\sigma\mathbf{P} = \sigma.$

Comment: Sorry, I just meant to say that you forgot one $1/5$.

Comment: Got it. Fixed now. Thanks.